# fix the position of a div

Tags: jquery, css

this is the css used

```
<style type="text/css">
#search_results{position:relative;height:369px;overflow:auto}
#floating{background-color:#eee;padding:15px;position:absolute;bottom:0px}
</style>
```

i need the floating div to be placed fixed at the bottom of the search results div.
if i apply the above css to the floating div, the div gets stuck at the bottom of the search results div and thats the expected. if i scroll the window, things are fine.
but now when i scroll inside the search_results div, the position of the floating div gets changed. i want it to be placed at the bottom of the search results div no matter if page is scrolled or the search results div is scrolled.i have tried the below script. its working fine in all browsers except ie. in ie, the div is positioned at the bottom but there are few jerks.. how to fix it to the bottom at all times,even if page is scrolled or the search results is scrolled

```
<div style="width:695px;border:1px solid red" id="search_results">
    <div id="floating">test block</div>
       <div style="padding:25px 0;border-bottom:1px solid green">       
          <div style="float:left">
            <p>test1</p>
            <p class="mrgBtm5px">random no</p>
            <p>
                <span>lorem ipsum</span><br/>
                <span>lorem ipsum expand</span>

            </p>
          </div>         
            <div style="clear:both"></div>  
        </div> 
        <div style="padding:25px 0;border-bottom:1px solid green">      
          <div style="float:left">
            <p>test1</p>
            <p class="mrgBtm5px">random no</p>
            <p>
                <span>lorem ipsum</span><br/>
                <span>lorem ipsum expand</span>

            </p>
          </div>         
            <div style="clear:both"></div>  
        </div>
         <div style="padding:25px 0;border-bottom:1px solid green">     
          <div style="float:left">
            <p>test1</p>
            <p class="mrgBtm5px">random no</p>
            <p>
                <span>lorem ipsum</span><br/>
                <span>lorem ipsum expand</span>

            </p>
          </div>         
            <div style="clear:both"></div>  
        </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the floating div out of the search div,

```
<div style="width:695px;border:1px solid red" id="search_results">

       <div style="padding:25px 0;border-bottom:1px solid green">       
          <div style="float:left">
            <p>test1</p>
            <p class="mrgBtm5px">random no</p>
            <p>
                <span>lorem ipsum</span><br/>
                <span>lorem ipsum expand</span>

            </p>
          </div>         
            <div style="clear:both"></div>  
        </div> 
        <div style="padding:25px 0;border-bottom:1px solid green">      
          <div style="float:left">
            <p>test1</p>
            <p class="mrgBtm5px">random no</p>
            <p>
                <span>lorem ipsum</span><br/>
                <span>lorem ipsum expand</span>

            </p>
          </div>         
            <div style="clear:both"></div>  
        </div>
         <div style="padding:25px 0;border-bottom:1px solid green">     
          <div style="float:left">
            <p>test1</p>
            <p class="mrgBtm5px">random no</p>
            <p>
                <span>lorem ipsum</span><br/>
                <span>lorem ipsum expand</span>

            </p>
          </div>         
            <div style="clear:both"></div>  
        </div> 
</div>
<div id="floating">test block</div>
```

and apply below css to it.

```
#floating {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 1px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: -51px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6Qyvy/5/show

You can also apply this css along with the above modified html,

```
#floating {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: -51px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6Qyvy/6/show/

Comment: works like a charm ! thanks a ton ! i was thinking how to achieve this through script. :( @SilverBlade

Comment: You could accept this answer so that it don't get rendered in the unanswered category :)